# Azure web app with mysqli_connect instead of PDO

Tags: php, mysql, azure, pdo

I have recently been successful with utilize the PDO connection instead of mysql_query, however I find PDO to be far complex and confusing, so I wish use the mysqli/mysqlconnet instead.

I noticed that uppgrading the php version on the azure app decerese the potenial error you can get, however I was wondering how can you make your app as close to as the localhost variation, with error been extremtly precise and simple to understand?

Here is the code mysql_querry con

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

    if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

PDO variation

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

<?php
function getFruit($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the app settings
[web app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9MWl.png)

Also what is the diffrent between utlizeing Connection String here

[mysql connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twd9i.png)
compare to utilize the php implmetion within in webmatrix

UPDATE here what I am basically trying to get to work. But I dunno why azure doesnt give me errors or anything. I have finally figured out that you can go into the console/kudu and change the php ini file

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM randomTable WHERE innhold LIKE '%$searchFunction%';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Ikke mulig og søke i db");
$antallrader = mysqli_num_rows($sqlResultat);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? As I have a test mysql connection on Azure using `mysqli` in PHP 7.0, it works fine on my side. Do you have any error message?

Comment: Yes what I want to do is this is use the mysqlli_querry insted of the PDO but I am not getting any errors or anything basically I have no idea why Azure does not support it. I have finally figured out some things that it is apprently off in the PHP.ini file and I am alittle bit confused how to fix it I will edit the question

Comment: If you were using a code from my answer, you'd have the error message first class

Comment: You mean if I put this mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); I will get error without going into the php.ini?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a production environment, Azure Web Apps Service do not enable the display errors in PHP runtime. For dev, you can config the setting `display_errors` in PHP ini config file. You can refer to [How to: Change the built-in PHP configurations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-change-the-built-in-php-configurations)
 for details.

Meanwhile, you can simply add the following code in your PHP script to enable to show the errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

And BTW, the PHP runtime on Azure Web Apps has supported the `mysqli` extension even in PHP 7.0. You can use `phpinfo()` to check all PHP runtime. 
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes this is exactly type of answer I was wondering about I mange to change my own php.ini on azure now I was just wondering if the command line like this one http://imgur.com/TOOqIaB has any influence on mysqlli and mysql ? Here is the windows azure web app phphttp://imgur.com/8b4LWZA

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "test";
$charset = "utf8";

// mysqli version
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset($charset)

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM City");
$data = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
foreach ($data as $row)
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['color'] . "\t";
    print $row['calories'] . "\n";
}

// PDO version
$dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM City");
foreach ($data as $row)
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['color'] . "\t";
    print $row['calories'] . "\n";
}
```

For the life of me I won't understand how is PDO version more confusing.

Comment: The example I used was complety, random I am taking about this part $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  with errors and nonsense it makes no sense. But do you know of any way to make it the azure apply with the mysql php libary method?

Comment: I am afraid you are using wrong wording. If some particular error message doesn't make sense for you, it doesn't mean it doesn't make sense at all. Either way, if you can't make any sense from the error message, you can always google for it. Most likely you will find both the explanation and the solution.